# What type of coffee maker is this?

Tags: espresso-machine, moka, coffee-machines, percolator

I got a stove top coffee maker, from my grandfather (not antique, he bought it recently). I am not sure what type it is. I claims to be a percolator, but functions more like a moka pot. They have given the nozzle to pour, in the top chamber. It heats water in bottom chamber, and the water passes through coffee powder, placed in between, and a brown liquid falls in the top, which is what I drink.

This is an Amazon.in link to that piece:
https://www.amazon.in/Pigeon-Xpresso-Stainless-Coffee-Perculator/dp/B072F17LRP/

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical [moka pot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moka_pot).

The confusion may stem from the fact that the principle of a moka pot is somewhat similar to a percolator, just without a back flow (sort of a “one way percolator”), and in some descriptions, including the German Wikipedia article on moka pots, the expression “percolator” is used.

Comment: Are there English translations of German Wikipedia article anywhere? I don't know German, but I want to read what it says.